# Avoid "recursive" function calls while unpacking variadic templates until runtime condition

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Basically, I want to find a template in a parameter pack that satisfies some runtime conditions. Intuitively, I just want to iterate over my instantiations of the parameter pack and find the first which satisfies a condition. My current simplified toy implementation to demonstrate what I mean:

*Find the struct of `X` and `Y` which satisfies their `test()` first.*

```cpp
struct X {
  bool test(int i) {
    flag = i > 10;
    return flag;
  }
  bool flag;
  std::string value = "X satisfied first";
};

struct Y {
  bool test(int i) {
    flag = i > 11;
    return flag;
  }
  bool flag;
  std::string value = "Y satiesfied first";
};
```

*This struct finds the first struct of `X` and `Y` to satisfy the condition. In this example it increases an integer up to a given limit until one of the structs reports that its `test()` was successful.*

```cpp
template <typename... Ts> struct FindFirst {
  static std::string find_first(int limit) {
    return find_first_satisfying(limit, Ts{}...);
  }

  static std::string find_first_satisfying(int limit, Ts... ts) {
    int i = 0;
    bool satisfied = false;
    while (i < limit && !satisfied) {
      satisfied = (ts.test(i) || ...);
      i++;
    }
    return extract(ts...);
  }

  template <typename T, typename... OtherTs>
  static std::string extract(T t, OtherTs... ts) {
    if (t.flag) {
      return t.value;
    } else {
      if constexpr (sizeof...(OtherTs) > 0) {
        return extract(ts...);
      } else {
        return "Nobody satiesfied condition";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This implementation generates as many different `extract()` functions with different signatures as there are templates in the pack. They get "recursively" called and result in a deep call stack (depends on the position of the satisfying struct) and large bytecode.

Is there a method to construct a loop (at compile-time) which tests each instantiation of the parameter pack and stops appropriately?
Also, any other suggestions on how to simplify the whole construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrote your code something like that:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::string find_first_satisfying(int limit, Ts... ts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != limit; ++i) {
      std::string res;
      bool found = false;
      ([&](){ if (ts.test(i)) { found = true; res = ts.value; } return found;}() || ...);
      if (found) { return res; }
    }
    return "Nobody satisfied condition";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35085cedd3882d07)

Answer (score 2):

No. It is possible that in C++23 it won't be like this but currently there is no guarantee.

But is there problem really? The only issue I see is that the code is hard to write and understand. Large bytecode is of little significance and optimizer should be able to inline and optimize everything - only debug performance should suffer as a result (and compile time)... Unless you write the program in a manner that makes optimizer/compiler unable to inline it (by hiding bodies of functions).

P.S. can't you somehow write extract as an operator and use the `...` instead of recursion? Though, I think it is a bad idea for various reasons. (I see that @Jarod42 wrote it via lambda in another answer, it looks good to me.)

Comment: I agree that the code is not very maintainable and am not too happy with the overall look of the code, too. I'm open to any suggestion, my only other idea was to pass a vector of a common base class of `X` and `Y` instead of the variadic templates.

Comment: @fresapore it is hard to give you a good answer to the question since I don't know the situation. It depends a lot on the context. 1) There is the KISS principle: keep it simple. Can't you work with one class? I mean not an interface parent of both - just one class?

Comment: @fresapore (2) indeed you can work with a parent interface class `Z`. I.e., the function becomes something like `template<size_t n> std::string find_first_satisfying(int limit, std::array<Z*,n>) {...}`. This can be a nice utility function but its performance might not be the best - so again it might be a good solution unless you call need to call it a billion times a second in real time program. In image processing, making pixel a class and then calling virtual functions on them is an excellent way to cripple your performance but if you use the function for strategic decisions then its fine.